# Merging ONE Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have one multidimensional array I need to merge. This one has two pockets, future arrays could have four or six. All solutions I find start with two arrays, but I only have one. This doesn't seem like it should be difficult, but I can't find a solution.

**I need this:**

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [51] => 1
    [52] => 1
  )

  [1] => Array (
    [75] => 1
    [76] => 1
  )
)
```

**To be this:**

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [51] => 1
    [52] => 1
    [75] => 1
    [76] => 1
  )
)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `foreach(){}`?

Comment: `[$array[0] + $array[1]]`

Comment: foreach() keeps giving me the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [Argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) operator `...` you can create a new array with the `array_replace()`...

```
$array = [[51 =>1 , 52=> 1], [75 =>1 , 76=> 1]];

$output = [array_replace([], ...$array)];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the keys are unique and you want to keep them:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_replace', $array);
```

If the keys aren't unique or you don't care if they are reset (they will be reset):

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```